# Moving a label in a circular path

Tags: java, trigonometry

I want to move a label in a GUI in a circular path.I hope to maintain the speed using threads.
Can anyone tell me how to do circular movement? What is the logic we should use for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the circumference formula : x^2 + y^2 = radius^2

Knowing that formula, if you know the radius you want (constant), you can do something like this (pseudocode, I hope you get the idea):

```
for (x from initial_x to end_x) {
   y = Math.sqrt(radius^2 - x^2)
   draw the label at position (x, y)
}
```

Comment: can you post full code for that? i'm not good at maths.very sorry

Comment: *"x^2 + y^2 = R"* -> x^2 + y^2 = **R^2**

Comment: void drawmethod(JLabel lb){
    try{
        double x,y;
        int x1,y1;
        for( x=0; x<380; x++){
            Thread.sleep(40);
            y = Math.sqrt(10-(x^2));
            x1 = (int)x; 
            y1 = (int)y;
            lb.setLocation(x1, y1);
            lb.setText("x("+x1+","+y1+")");
           }
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
}

i try this code.But it give a error on y = Math.sqrt(10-(x^2)); line.what is the error?how to correct that?

Comment: Please don't include code in comments.  Edit it into the question using code formatting.

Comment: *"But it give a error .. what is the error?"*  Your first error is not copy/pasting the error output that you see.  How do you expect us to guess?

Comment: after compiling above code lable moving on only horizontal plane.it is not moving in a circular path. y = Math.sqrt(5-(Math.pow(x, 2))); i give 5 as radius value.is it correct?

Comment: Thank you Andrew. Fixed. user1150071, please use 25 (5^2) instead of 5.

Comment: even fixing that value it is not printing a circle. just label moving left to right..

Comment: Please update the question with the code you are using, so we can help you more efficiently.

Comment: The given solution shows constant speed along the x-axis. If your want constant speed along the curve of the circle, use the parameterized formula: with t ranging from 0 to 2 pi: x = radius * cos(t) and y = radius * sin(t) -- of course you may add constant offsets to x and y to position the label where you need it. Shift the range of t to let the label start at another angle of the circle.